# Inertia post in Chrome, Edge give page expired

Tags: post, csrf, inertiajs

My Laravel app is in production, and I have a simple form, basically just an email input and conditions accepted checkbox, that is Inertia.posted to the controller. It works in Firefox, but in Chrome and Edge I get a page expired error.

Definitely a CSRF issue, as disabling the verification removes the error. What I can't figure out is why, as Inertia's documentation states that "Laravel automatically includes the proper CSRF token when making requests via Inertia".

Yet the X-XSRF-TOKEN is sent with the request headers in Firefox, but not Chrome or Edge.

The form:

```
<form class="" @submit.prevent="submit">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="">
                        <input id="email" v-model="form.email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-3/12 pl-6">
                        <button type="submit" :disabled="form.processing" class=" pb-3 pr-2 flex justify-center font-ropa text-transform: uppercase text-white bg-gray-500 pr-1 pt-2 p-1">
                            

                            <h1 class="pt-1">Sign up</h1>

                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label class="mt-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="terms" v-model="form.terms" name="agree">
                    I have read and agree with the <Link :href="('/terms')">
                    Confidentiality agreement and HTTP cookies
                </Link>
                </label>
            </form>

const form = reactive({
email: null,
terms: null,
})

function submit() {
console.log(form)
Inertia.post('/mailinglist', form)
}
```

Comment: It turns out the issue was that Same-Site cookies in my session.php were set to none instead of lax.